# Hibernate: Column names based on table name?

Tags: hibernate, orm

In my company, we have this naming convention for table columns:

Table: `TCARS`
Columns: `TCARS_ID, TCARS_BRAND_ID, TCARS_MODEL_ID`... etc.

I currently have this entity class:

```
@Table(name="TCARS")
public class CarEntity {
    @Column(name="TCARS_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="TCARS_BRAND_ID")
    private int brandId;

    // etc
}
```

I would like to write my class like this:

```
@Table(name="TCARS")
public class CarEntity {
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="BRAND_ID")
    private int brandId;

    // etc
}
```

...and use an Hibernate [NamingStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy.html) to complete the column names based on table name. The problem I have is that on NamingStrategy interface, I can't access table names while I'm configuring column name, so I'm unable to prefix the column names with the table name.

Is there any solution tho this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate has a BeforeBind event on the configuration class, maybe Hibernate too.

```
// pseudocode
Hibernate.Cfg.Configuration config;

config.BeforeBindMapping + eventhandler
{
    HbmClass c = RootClasses[0];

    foreach(IColumnsMapping hascolumns in c.Items.OfType<IColumnsMapping>())
    {
        hascolumns.Columns[0].Text = c.Table.Name + hascolumns.Columns[0].Text;
    }
};
```

Comment: Sadly, I didn't find anything similar to the BeforeBindMapping in Hibernate. Thanks anyway!